# Convert Custom Field image to become Featured Image in WordPress?

Tags: image, wordpress

I run a css gallery and I need to convert all the images in the gallery from a Custom Field to become the Featured Image.
Does anyone have any advice how I could do this?

Comment: What's the name of the custom field, and what kind of data does it currently hold (attachment ID, filename, serialized data...)?

Comment: The custom field name is "Feature Image" and the value is a url path to an image, mostly from the media library.  I'm using TimThumb to resize the image, but it's weighing too heavy on the server.  So I want to use the native WordPress image attachment post-thumbnails function.

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly, if you want to avoid TimThumb entirely and your images aren't currently the right size, you'll need to [find a plugin that can batch resize your media library](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+batch+resize+images).

Once you've done that, we can attempt to automate the process of finding the attachment for each featured image (that is, the post entry in the `wp_posts` table), and setting the post thumbnail.

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();

// Get all attachment IDs and filenames
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'");

// Create an 'index' of attachment IDs and their filenames
$attachments = array();
foreach ($results as $row)
    $attachments[ intval($row->post_id) ] = $row->meta_value;

// Get all featured images
$images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value AS 'url' FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Featured Image'");

// Loop over each image and try and find attachment post
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (preg_match('#^https?://#', $image->url))
        $image->url = str_replace($uploads['baseurl'], '', $image->url); // get relative URL if absolute

    $filename = ltrim($image->url, '/');

    if ($attachment_ID = array_search($filename, $attachments)) {
        // found attachment, set post thumbnail and delete featured image
        update_post_meta($image->post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_ID);
        delete_post_meta($image->post_ID, 'Featured Image');
    }
}
```

### Disclaimer

There is no guarantee that the code above will work, it's purely based on the information I have gauged from your comments so far - it's more of a suggestion than a one-stop solution.

Comment: The script I'm planning on using is from Victor Teixeira http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15311, which utilizes native post-thumbnail, so I wouldn't need to batch resize the images.  I'm not sure how to call the script you've offered above; though it seems like it should work.  thanks for your help.  much appreciated.

Comment: This script works like a charm for new posts.  If I continue using custom fields, it automatically adds the image to the post-thumbnails as well.  I can't seem to get the images from the current custom fields to transfer to the post-thumbnail attachment field

Comment: The script I posted above was an example that would need to run only once - either in a plugin or just dropped in your `functions.php` - but as I say, I don't know enough to guarantee it would work - I'd need to take a look at your database or the original featured image code.